# Implement CPU limiting feature provided by Windows Security Essential in a Win32 application

Tags: winapi, windows-7, cpu-usage

In Windows 7, Windows Security Essential has a setting which limits CPU during scan to specified value in percentages. Now I want to implement this feature in my application.

I have written a Win32 application which will be used in Windows 7. The application utilizes more than 85% of the CPU. How can I limit this CPU usage of the application programmatically in Win32?

Comment: You'd have to call Sleep() inside your hot loop to yield the processor.  The usually more sane way to go about it is to call SetThreadPriority().

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the reply. As you suggested, if SetThreadPriority() is used, the application utilizes high CPU when CPU is at idle state. I want the application to use limited CPU always.

Comment: Of course, that's why it is the sane solution.  An idle processor is a big waste of system resources when you actually have useful work to do.